# SDK error in Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, windows-store, construct-2

Upon rebuilding the solution to a file in Visual Studio exported from Construct 2 I received errors:

```
MSB3774 Could not find SDK "Microsoft.WinJS.2.0, Version-1.0"

MSB3774 Could not find SDK "Microsoft.WinJS.2.1, Version-1.0"
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open Visual Studio

Click File->New Project

Click Windows

Click Windows 8

There will be an option there to install the Windows 8.1 tools.

Comment: Interface must have changed... There is no "Windows" option to click in VS 2015 in the New Project Dialog

Comment: I went back to the VS installer and found an option to install the Windows 8.1 tools.... 8GB, really?  Surely there is a more lightweight option for installing the WinJS SDK

Comment: @PartapDavis Where did you find that option?